# Java NoSuchMethodError: main

Tags: java, macos

I am learning Java on OS X through terminal. When I compile the code below I do not get any errors but When I try to run it I get

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main

My code:

```
public class Problem5{
public void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 1;
    while(!checkMod(n)){
        n++;
    }

}
public boolean checkMod(int in)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=1; i<20; i++)
    {
        if(in%i == 0)
        {
            count = count + 1; 
        }
    }
    if(count ==19)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

I removed "static" from the main method because I am calling the checkMod method.

How do I code this correctly?

Thanks

Comment: what command are you using to run class from terminal?

Comment: mac:Java name$ javac Problem5.java
mac:Java name$ java Problem5

Comment: why are u using terminal. Use Eclipse or Netbeans rather.

Comment: declare main method as static and call checkmod method with object as u cant call non-static method from static method..

Comment: `return count == 19;` is more readable (IMHO)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every executable Java program requires at least one class that implements `public static void main(String args[])` in order to run.

Rather then removing the `static` reference from `main`, either

Add `static` to the `public boolean checkMod(int in)` ie `public static boolean checkMod(int in)`

or

Call the method `checkMod` from the instance level.

```
public class Problem5{
    public void main(String[] args) {
        new Problem5();
    }

    public Problem5() {
        int n = 1;
        while(!checkMod(n)){
            n++;
        }

    }

    // Rest of code...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the info! This really helps. 
When would you want to create an instance vs having several static methods?

Comment: `static` references are really good for utilities methods, things that don't require a reference to any instance objects, methods or variables.  You want to use instances when you want more then one, well, instance of the object, such as `Person`.  You program would be pretty useless if the `Person` class only used `static` references, you'd only ever be able to have one `Person`, BUT, you could use a `static` method to calculate the age, based a `Person`'s date of birth

Answer (score 1):

main need to be `static`: `public static void main(String[] args)`

Answer (score 1):

The "entry-point" method is static main instead of main. They have different method signature. JVM will only search for static main. 
You can make your

```
public boolean checkMod(int in)
```

as

```
static public boolean checkMod(int in)
```

Answer (score 1):

`static` is required for the main method. You can use something like this to add state to your main execution:

```
public class Problem5 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Problem5().start();
  }

  private void start() {
    int n = 1;
    while(!checkMod(n)){
      n++;
    }
  }

  private boolean checkMod(int in) {
    ..
  }
}
```

On the other hand, your `checkMod(int)` method doesn't need state. You could also just add the `static` keyword to it as well. It can then be called by the static main method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare 'static' on both main and checkMod.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `checkMod` static as well, because you're calling it from another static method. You cannot call an instance method from a static method:

```
public class Problem5{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 1;
    while(!checkMod(n)){
        n++;
    }

}
public static boolean checkMod(int in)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=1; i<20; i++)
    {
        if(in%i == 0)
        {
            count = count + 1; 
        }
    }
    if(count ==19)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Main method should always be declared as `static`. Also you are accessing `checkMod` in main method so either declare `checkMod` also as `static` or access it with object as you can not access non-static method from static method.

Try following.

```
public class Problem5{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 1;
    while(!new Problem5().checkMod(n)){
        n++;
    }

}
public boolean checkMod(int in)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=1; i<20; i++)
    {
        if(in%i == 0)
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }
    if(count ==19)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
}
```